# Force derived class to implement method with Generics - C#

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

Is it possible to have an abstract base class force its derived classes to implement a specific method with generics while still being able to use the abstract base class elsewhere? Here's what I mean:

```
public abstract class BaseFieldValue<ToutputType,TinputType>
{
   public abstract ToutputType DoStuff(TinputType input);
}

public class StringField:BaseFieldValue<string,string>
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public override string DoStuff(string input)
    {
        //Custom implementation for this class
    }
}


public class Project
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public List<BaseFieldValue> ProjectFields {get;set;} //ERROR
}
```

The inheritance of `BaseFieldValue` -> `StringField` compiles fine, but when I try to use `List<BaseFieldValue>` on `Project` it doesn't like the syntax because it wants the generic types defined. Is what I'm trying to do even possible or is there a better approach?

I'm currently implementing an interface on all these derived classes, but this forces me to remember it needs to go on each of them. I'd like the generic contract to be enforced on any class that derives form `BaseFieldValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your generic base class inherit a non-generic base class or interface:

```
public abstract class BaseFieldValue 
{
}

public abstract class BaseFieldValue<ToutputType,TinputType> : BaseFieldValue
{
   public abstract ToutputType DoStuff(TinputType input);
}
```

> I'm currently implementing an interface on all these derived classes...

In that case, you might consider just using this interface instead of an abstract base class.

```
public abstract class BaseFieldValue<ToutputType,TinputType> : IFieldValue
{
    ...
}

public class Project
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public List<IFieldValue> ProjectFields {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: This is great, I didn't realize I could structure it that way. Thanks for your help!